# Pyspark - Within each ID, I am looking to assign weights based on position of row

Tags: pyspark

Disclaimer: I am very new to Pyspark and am looking to learn.

Here is my dataset:

```
+----------+--------------------+
|install_id|influencer_date_time|
+----------+--------------------+
|  68483732| 2020-05-28 22:56:43|
|  68483732| 2020-05-28 23:21:53|
|  68483732| 2020-05-29 00:03:21|
|  68483732| 2020-05-29 00:05:21|
|  68486103| 2020-06-01 00:37:38|
|  68486103| 2020-06-01 00:59:30|
|  68486103| 2020-06-01 01:59:30|
|  68486110| 2020-06-01 00:59:30|
|  68486110| 2020-06-30 22:35:46|
+----------+--------------------+
```

Here is the rule I am trying to implement:

Within each `install_id`, 40% credit is assigned to each the first and last row, and the remaining 20% is distributed evenly to the middle rows. Now, if there are only 2 rows, then each row will get 50%.

This is how it would look in the sample dataset above:

```
+----------+--------------------+------+
|install_id|influencer_date_time|weight|
+----------+--------------------+------+
|  68483732| 2020-05-28 22:56:43|0.4   |
|  68483732| 2020-05-28 23:21:53|0.1   |
|  68483732| 2020-05-29 00:03:21|0.1   |
|  68483732| 2020-05-29 00:05:21|0.4   |
|  68486103| 2020-06-01 00:37:38|0.4   |
|  68486103| 2020-06-01 00:59:30|0.2   |
|  68486103| 2020-06-01 01:59:30|0.4   |
|  68486110| 2020-06-01 00:59:30|0.5   |
|  68486110| 2020-06-30 22:35:46|0.5   |
+----------+--------------------+------+
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Let me know if you'd like any additional details.

Comment: in ur input u have 4 entries with `68486103` and in output u have 3 entries with `68486103` ?

Comment: Apologies, that was a mistake. The input and output should be correct now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using **`row_number`** and **`max`** with **`window functions`** and **`when`** clause.

*You can remove third when clause if there is no case where there is only one entry of install_id.*

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().partitionBy("install_id").orderBy("influencer_date_time")
w1=Window().partitionBy("install_id")

df.withColumn("rowNum", F.row_number().over(w))\
  .withColumn("max", F.max("rowNum").over(w1))\
  .withColumn("weight",F.when((F.col("max")>2) & ((F.col("rowNum")==1)|(F.col("rowNum")==F.col("max"))),F.lit(0.4))\
                  .when((F.col("max")>2) & ((F.col("rowNum")!=1)|(F.col("rowNum")!=F.col("max"))), (0.2/(F.col("max")-2)))\
                  .when(F.col("max")==1, F.lit(1.0))\
                  .when((F.col("max")==2),F.lit(0.5))).drop('rowNum','max').orderBy("install_id").show()

#+----------+--------------------+------+
#|install_id|influencer_date_time|weight|
#+----------+--------------------+------+
#|  68483732| 2020-05-28 22:56:43|0.4   |
#|  68483732| 2020-05-28 23:21:53|0.1   |
#|  68483732| 2020-05-29 00:03:21|0.1   |
#|  68483732| 2020-05-29 00:05:21|0.4   |
#|  68486103| 2020-06-01 00:37:38|0.4   |
#|  68486103| 2020-06-01 00:59:30|0.2   |
#|  68486103| 2020-06-01 01:59:30|0.4   |
#|  68486110| 2020-06-01 00:59:30|0.5   |
#|  68486110| 2020-06-30 22:35:46|0.5   |
#+----------+--------------------+------+
```